# First sentence after figur/table not aligned

Tags: tables, floats, align

Im using a simple figure environment but at some times the first sentence after the image or table aren't aligned anymore. The text is off a few cm to the right. I modified my paragraph setting to be another subsubsubsection with this code, could this be the problem?

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}



\section{1}
\subsection{1}
some text
\subsubsection
some text, then the full page image follows on a new page
           \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.24]{Bilder/Imag.png} 
                \caption[bla]{bla}
                \label{fig:xxx}
                \end{figure}
           First not aligned Sentence
    normal text
```

Comment: Could that be just a normal paragraph indent?  Is there a blank line in your input file **before or after** the `figure` environment that would trigger a paragraph break?

Comment: I thought that would be the case and after deleting the blank lines some sentences were aligned but others weren't

Comment: In that case, you will need to recreate that behavior in a small example and edit your question to post the full example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Im fairly new to Latex and this site. Posting my full input file would be too long (maybe i misunderstood you). If i just add the full page image with the caption and afterwards the text in a new file, the misalignment doesn't happen. Is it there a problem before the image?

Comment: You need to copy your large input to a working file.  Then start removing as much code as possible while still getting this undesired result.  When you have finally removed as much code as possible, but still can get the undesirable result, that is the code you want to post, as an edit to your question.

Comment: i edited my question and it might have something to do with the paragraph change?

Comment: @SilvanIten We appreciate that you post a code, but please add some `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`s, `\begin{document}`, etc. to make it compilable. Read more in [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344).

Comment: @campa thank god that was it. Thanks for all the other comments especially the one about making the code compile for others. Really apreciate it!